# how to set "$.mobile.changePage" transition time?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

How can I set the "Sliding" time in below code?

```
$.mobile.changePage("#page37", { transition: "slideup"});
```

I tried {transition: "slideup", delay: 1000} but no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transition time cannot be modified with a `changePage()` parameter. You can however customize transitions as described [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-customtransitions.html).
The default transition times in jquery mobile are defined with the following CSS

```
.in {
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
-webkit-animation-duration: 350ms;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
-moz-animation-duration: 350ms;
}
```

Comment: In which case accepting the answer is probably the best thing to do :-)